# "Add New Item" Link on Page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, item-added

My customer would like to move the "Add New Item" to the top of a list. How can I accomplish this without adding significant code to the site?

Comment: Can you specify on which SharePoint Version you are asking for?

Comment: 2010 Foundation

Comment: Try given answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in SharePoint 2010 than Unfortunately you can't move the "Add New Item" link to the top of the OOBT list view web part.

An alternative approach is to add a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) on top of the list view web part with the following HTML source. (assuming the list name = "custom")

```
<a onclick='NewItem2(event, "/Lists/custom/NewForm.aspx"); return false;' href="javascript://">Add new item</a>
```

I had given this answer for SP 2010 because in SP 2013 it is already placed above the list.

Comment: This is a good answer, so +1.  I've always told my users that Microsoft did this because the ribbon control to add new item was already at the top of the list.  If the user clicks in white space in the title of the webpart, the ribbon for the list is displayed and the first icon is the New Item icon.